# iOS - access class method using targets

Tags: ios, xcode, targets

I have the following code:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navControllerInstance = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([MyViewController class])];
```

When I use targets my problem is `[MyViewController class]` is returning `"MyTarget_2.MyViewController"` then my app crash because `"'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x600001e65d80>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier "`

I have two targets:
**MyTarget** and **MyTarget_2** and is only failing with the last one.

I don't understand is why **[MyViewController class]** is returning
**MyTarget.MyViewController**. When I start a new project this is not happening, only returns **MyViewController** . Why is such a difference?

This seems to be related because I'm using swift+objective-c
[Calling NSStringFromClass on a Swift Class in Objective-C returns module mangled name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26927050/2139691)

Comment: Simple solution will be using string @"MyViewController" or defining some constant for that string and using it instead of deriving it from `NSStringFromClass...`. Is there a reason you are avoiding it?

Comment: What do you mean bei "When I use targets ..."? And can you complete the error message? "... doesn't contain a view controller with identifier ..."?

Comment: @AndréSlotta I mean, when i compile with MyTarget is everything ok, but when I compile with MyTarget_2 then I got crash.

Comment: @VivekMolkar you are right but I'm looking for an elegant solution, I think this could became a mayor problem.

Comment: Are you sure that **all** storyboards and classes are included in **all** targets? And what is the *identifier* in the error message? You did not paste it completely...

Comment: @AndréSlotta yes they are included in all targets.

Comment: Can you share your project?

Comment: @AndréSlotta nope :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153315/discussion-between-andre-slotta-and-ricardo).

Answer (score 0):

You can get class name like this :

```
NSString *className = [[NSStringFromClass([MyViewController class]) componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] lastObject];
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navControllerInstance = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:className];
```

and make sure that your storyboard id should be `MyViewController`

Comment: I'm getting the same error `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x600000672200>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'MyViewController''`

Answer (score 0):

Did you give Identifier to your ViewController in storyboard ?

You can give it against Storyboard ID in ViewController's identify Inspector section.

Because ,

```
UINavigationController *navControllerInstance = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([MyViewController class])];
```

method work on the **identifier** and not on **class name**

Comment: is your identifier same as your class name ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't copied that particular storyboard in to your target. You can verify it. Click on target. Then on Build Phase -> Copy bundle resource. Check if storyboard file exist in both targets. And if storyboard is not there click on + button add that file. Clean and run. Hope it help.

Comment: I have check and they are added.

Comment: Okay have you checked out whether you clicked on the checkbox to use the storyboad ID ?

Comment: Yes, is checked to all targets.