# Custom Init ViewController in Swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, init

---

I have code in obj-c

```
+(id)viewController
{
    UIViewController *vc = [[self alloc]init];
    return vc;
}
```

But I cannot reproduce this in swift code I try in this way

```
   class  func viewController()->UIViewController
    {
        return self();
    }
  convenience override  init () {
        var nibName = NSStringFromClass(self.dynamicType) // In this part I get err
        self.init(nibName:nibName,bundle:nil);

    }
```

I cannot get self class name before init ... in obj-c its look like this

```
NSString *nibName = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];
```

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24107658/get-a-user-readable-version-of-the-class-name-in-swift-in-objc-nsstringfromclas

Comment: not exactly my problems is when I will use this I don't know childer controller name (Thats why I use self)