# Get Swift class name in "class func" method

Tags: ios, swift, function, class, static

I have a static method in Swift

```
class BaseAsyncTask: WebServiceClient {
      class func execute(content : [String:AnyObject], cancelled:CustomBool)
      {
            // Print class name (BaseAsyncTask) here
      }
}
```

And I want to know how to get the class name inside that method. I tried

```
self.dynamicType
```

but that gives error (I suppose because of the self inside a class function)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are different methods to do that, if your method inherits from NSObject you can expose it to objective-c and do something like that.

```
@objc(BaseAsyncTask)

class BaseAsyncTask: WebServiceClient {
      class func execute(content : [String:AnyObject], cancelled:CustomBool)
      {
            println("Class \(NSStringFromClass(self))")
      }
}
```

For pure SWIFT introspection check here about [MirrorType](http://nshipster.com/mirrortype/)

I've found also this extension credits to [ImpactZero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24107658/get-a-user-readable-version-of-the-class-name-in-swift-in-objc-nsstringfromclas)

```
public extension NSObject{
    public class var nameOfClass: String{
        return NSStringFromClass(self).components(separatedBy: ".").last!
    }

    public var nameOfClass: String{
        return NSStringFromClass(type(of: self)).components(separatedBy: ".").last!
    }
}
```

**[Xcode 8]**
Alex suggested me that in the Xcode 8 version this code shows a warning. To avoid that we should prefix the method like that:

```
@nonobjc class var className: String{ 
   return NSStringFromClass(self).components(separatedBy: ".").last!
}
```

Comment: NSStringFromClass(self).componentsSeparatedByString(".").last! worked as a charm. Didn't occur to me to try self without dynamicType, thanks.

Comment: @Andrea, I would also suggest to add `@nonobjc` attribute before `public class var nameOfClass` to avoid the following warning (Xcode 8.2):
"ld: warning: Some object files have incompatible Objective-C category definitions. Some category metadata may be lost. All files containing Objective-C categories should be built using the same compiler." Like so: `@nonobjc class var className: String{ return NSStringFromClass(self).components(separatedBy: ".").last! }`

Answer (score 10):

You can use string interpolation to print `self`:

```
let className = "\(self)"
```

Sample code:

```
class BaseAsyncTask: WebServiceClient {
    class func execute(content : [String:AnyObject], cancelled: CustomBool)
    {
        let className = "\(self)"
        print(className)
    }
}

class AnotherAsyncTask : BaseAsyncTask {
}

BaseAsyncTask.execute([:], cancelled: true) // prints "BaseAsyncTask"
AnotherAsyncTask.execute([:], cancelled: true) // prints "AnotherAsyncTask"
```

Comment: Wow! Great solution.

Answer (score 7):

Another way to do this, when you don't have an instance of the class is this.

**Swift 4**

```
print(String(describing:BaseAsyncTask.self))
```

**Swift 2**

```
print(String(BaseAsyncTask))
```

Inspired here.

[Get class name of object as string in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24494784/get-class-name-of-object-as-string-in-swift)

Comment: This doesn't work in Swift 4. You need to use something like: `String(describing:BaseAsyncTask.self)`