# Print Struct name in swift

Tags: swift, struct

It is possible to know the name of a struct in swift ? I know this is possible for `class`:

**Example**

```
class Example {
   var variable1 = "one"
   var variable2 = "2"
}
```

printing this class name, I would simply do:

```
NSStringFromClass(Example).componentsSeparatedByString(".").last!
```

but can I do something similar for `struct` ?

**Example**

If i have a `struct` :

```
struct structExample {
   var variable1 = "one"
   var variable2 = "2"
}
```

how can I get the name *"**structExample**"* of this `struct`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you need the name of the non instanciated struct you can ask for its `self`:

```
struct StructExample {
    var variable1 = "one"
    var variable2 = "2"
}

print(StructExample.self) // prints "StructExample"
```

For an instance I would use CustomStringConvertible and dynamicType:

```
struct StructExample: CustomStringConvertible {
    var variable1 = "one"
    var variable2 = "2"
    var description: String {
        return "\(self.dynamicType)"
    }
}

print(StructExample()) // prints "StructExample"
```

Regarding **Swift 3**, `self.dynamicType` has been renamed to `type(of: self)` for the example here.

Answer (score 9):

The pure Swift version of this works for structs just like for classes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31050781/2203005.

If you want to work on the type object itself:

```
let structName = "\(structExample.self)"
```

If you have an instance of the struct:

```
var myInstance = structExample()
let structName = "\(myInstance.dynamicType)"
```

Funny enough the Type object returned does not seem to conform to the CustomStringConvertible protocol. Hence it has no 'description' property, though the "" pattern still does the right thing.

Answer (score 5):

```
print("\(String(describing: Self.self))")
```

Answer (score 2):

Convenience protocol with extension:

```
public protocol Describable {
    var typeName: String { get }
}

extension Describable {
    public var typeName: String {
        return String(describing: Self.self)
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
struct AccountLoginRequest: Equatable, Codable, Describable
{
    let email: String?
    let password: String?

    var description: String {
        return "[\(typeName) email=\(email), password=\(password)]"
    }
}
```