# In Swift 4, how can you get the string-representation of a data type stored in a variable of type 'Any'?

Tags: swift, types, swift4

What is the easiest way to get the string-representation of a value's data type if that value is stored in an 'Any' variable?

For instance, I'm debugging code that has this...

```
extension SomeClass : Mappable{

    static func map(value:Any) -> SomeClass{

        return Parse(value)

    }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out what data types are being passed through the function, but if I use type(of:) I keep getting 'Any' and not the value held in it.

```
extension SomeClass : Mappable{

    static func map(value:Any) -> SomeClass{

        let nameOfType = ??? <-- This is what I'm trying to figure out
        log(nameOfType)

        return Parse(value)

    }
}
```

I simply want to print the data type to the debug window, not do testing with `is` or `as`, etc.  It's strictly for logging/debugging reasons.

Comment: `String.init(describing:value)`? You can override `description` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2427941-init) if needed.

Comment: No, that's a string representation of the *value*.  I want the string representation of the *data type* *of* that value.

Comment: Do you mean this code snippet returns 'Any'?

func map(value: Any) {
    print(type(of: value))
}

let value = 67
map(value: value)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41196105/1801544 then maybe some ideas?

Comment: `print(type(of: value))` works fine for me in a playground...is this the exact code you're working with?

Comment: I get 'Any' when I do that.  What are you getting?

Comment: Also keep in mind that the type can be Optional<Any>

Comment: String if I pass a String, Int if I pass an Int, etc. I obviously don't have your whole class so it's just with a Test example

Comment: @MarqueIV I get 'Int' as expected. Therefore, I gave that example.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out.  It's a two-step process.

You have to:

1. Use `type(of:)` to get the type of the variable (as others have described)
2. Use `String(describing:)` to get the name of that type (that was the missing piece)

Here's an example...

```
let typeName = String(describing: type(of:value))
```

That's what I was after. Thanks for the other answers. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
static func map(value:AnyObject) -> AnyClass{

    return value.classForCoder

}
```

Or

```
static func map(value:Any) -> AnyClass{

    return (value as AnyObject).classForCoder

}
```

Comment: This isn't what I'm after.  Just like the other answer above, this changes the return type of the function. I'm trying to debug. I'm trying to log what's passed in.  (I've updated the question to be more clear.)

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4 you can achieve that like this:

```
static func map(value: Any) -> Any.Type {
    return type(of: value)
}
```

Comment: This changes the return type of the function.  I'm trying to debug what's being passed to an existing function, not change the function. Make sense? (I've updated the question to be more clear.)